# placing war file in the webapps subdirectory of the servlet container’s installation directory

Tags: tomcat6, servlet, containers

i am trying to install a particular [software](http://docs.geonode.org/en/latest/deploy/install.html#geonetwork-with-geonode-schema) and it is asking me to place the .war file in the webapps subdirectory of the servlet container's installation directory. I am not sure which location is this exactly. I know that the tomcat 6 webapps directory is in /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps but is this the directory where i should dump the .war file according to the installation guide?

Google is giving me back the links to installation guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Assuming that tomcat is your servlet container (that you're not trying to get this to run in Glassfish or Jetty or some other servlet container) and tomcat is located at /var/lib/tomcat6, then you want to put the .war file in /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps and restart tomcat.